# make modules_install restarts configuration process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile a Linux kernel version (linux-2.6.32.60) for my Debian machine.
The first step was to create a configuration file (.config) by typing:

> make xconfig

Once the configuration file was created, I simply ran make, to build the image kernel and modules. Up to that point no problem.

However, when installing the modules (.ko files), I type:

> make modules_install

which instead of installing the newly compiled modules, brings a command line configuration setup, which is incorrect (the configuration file was already created).

Any ideas what is causing the configuration to be restarted?

Regards.

Comment: Btw, CONFIG_MODULES is set to y in my .config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was caused because of a development environment variable in my O.S setting ARCH to be i386 (that was required for running some infrastructure in our office). Since my kernel runs in a 64-bit processor and xconfig relies on a variable with the same name, the resulting .config file was being generated for a 32-bit architecture, and so was the whole compilation process. In the end, this was causing the installation error (which is indeed expected).

Answer (score 5):

Set the ARCH variable before calling menuconfig

```
$ make ARCH=arm menuconfig
```

Comment: You also should pass `CROSS_COMPILE` if you use it: `$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- menuconfig` ( http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Linux_Kernel_Users_Guide ).

Comment: @Gluttton CROSS_COMPILE is only needed to compile, not to create the confguration.